# What is the Reason for Noble Dukkha and How?

Tags: nirvana, attachment, dukkha, four-noble-truths

The direct answer to this question is `attachment` (`upadana`). To be more specific my question is how `attachment` become the cause for the `Noble Dukkha`?
Eg: If I like a car, its an attachment. And how does that become the cause for the `Noble Dhukka`

Comment: Let's keep this in one piece and edit the first question to add more details from this one.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov Noted.

Comment: attachment is dukkha because it is painful. imagine you see your lover kissing & embracing another person. Immediately you suffer. You are stabbed in the heart due to egoism or attachment. The Buddha said conceiving self (MN 140) is an arrow; a dart; a cancer; a tumour. I recommend to focus on real things rather than on superstitions about past lives. Regards

Comment: @Dhammadhatu, Thanks for the answer, but it's bit hard to think this is the `Noble Dukkha` because, its pretty straight forward. And assume the other way round if my lover is so loving to me then I'm happy. In that case attachment is not dukkha, is it?

Comment: When the mind is pure, it also knows lust & love are disturbing. The dhamma cannot be known when the mind remains impure. For example, when the mind experiences the 4th jhana, it realises the rapture & happiness sensations of the 1st & 2nd & 3rd jhanas are disturbing compared to the purity of the 4th jhana. Its the same with sexual love. The pure mind feels lust is suffering. Regards

Comment: I agreed on that, But still it doesn't answer my question, which is how attachment is become as Noble Dukkha.

Comment: `And assume the other way round if my lover is so loving to me then I'm happy. In that case attachment is not dukkha, is it?` The 1st noble truth says that, among other things, death is dukkha. And the 2nd noble truth says that the cause of dukkha is attachment. So, when your lover dies, ...

Comment: @ChrisW The death or the birth is not about what you think. If it is the death you meant how come the gold and silver is born and dead. Refer Aryaparyesana Sutta

Comment: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.026.than.html

Comment: @follower Did you agree with [footnote 2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.026.than.html#fn-2) of the link you posted?

Comment: No in Sri Lankan Canon gol and silver is not excluded, its there. I can confirm on this.